# How to add more than one column in ipad monotouch application?

Tags: ipad, uitableview, xamarin.ios

```
I am using a UISplitViewController in my application. In this SplitViewController on the left hand side i have A NavigationController and on right side i have a DetailViewController.

On my navigation controller i have UITableViewController which is used for navigating through the hierarchy of data.
```

When i am selecting a record(cell) from the table, i want to display its details on the detail view controller.

```
 I want the data to be displayed in following format:

 Name:       Matthew
 Age:        24
 City:       Newyork

 My problem is, i dont know how to add more than one column in the UITableView.

 Another question is that how to edit the values from this table?

 I want to edit the cells from table.

 For example, i want to edit the details from above table to:

 Name:    George Matthew
 Age:     24
 City:    Newyork


 In short i want to place labels in the forst column and text boxes in the second column of my table.

 Please help me out.
```

Thanks,
Neha

Answer (score 0):

In a tableview there is no two columns but instead you can add subviews in the single column itself.

Do in your cellForRowIndex delegate 
In your case create a Label assign the frame(x,y,width,height) values corresponding to that particular cell. Then add this label as a subview to the cell. Now for the textfield same as label now increase its x value higher so that it will be on rightside of tableview.

Comment: Hi, I m still not clear. What is a cellForRowIndex delegate? Do u mean to say that i need to add a Label and a textbox in each cell in the table in the "GetCell" method where we declare the contents of the cell?

Comment: Do i need to create a separate class file for this table or i can create a subclass for this table in my DetailViewcontroller.cs file itself?

Comment: See this both tutorials  http://doronkatz.com/ipad-programming-tutorial-hello-world   http://blancer.com/tutorials/i-phone/77006/uitableview-adding-subviews-to-a-cells-content-view/